# how to resolve "the value's length for key 'data source' exceeds its limit of '128'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, sql-server-express

Connection String

```
<add name="CostAllocationEntities2" connectionString="Data Source=PC210090\SQLEXPRESS; 
 Initial Catalog=testdb3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=password-1;
 multipleactiveresultsets=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is my function

```
public void GetBackup(string strDBName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strDBName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Server Name & Database can not be Blank");
        return;
    }
    else
    {                
        string destinationPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BackupDestinationPath");
        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CostAllocationEntities2"].ConnectionString);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[strDBName];
```

The last line is causing an Inner exception. and the message is

> Exception - Failed to connect to server Data Source=PC210090\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=testdb3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=password-1;multipleactiveresultsets=True; . Inner Exception : "The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'."}

Not Sure if anything is wrong with my connection string, as data is being fetched correctly into the dropdown boxes.

Comment: Why you error title and your Inner Exception doesnt match?

Comment: Exception - Failed to connect to server Data Source=PC210090\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=testdb3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=password-1;multipleactiveresultsets=True; .

Inner Exception : "The value's length for key 'data source' exceeds it's limit of '128'."}

Comment: No make it a comment, just update the question. I already improve the format for you.

Comment: Any solution to fix this issue?